# Deleting a contractible subspace is the same as deleting a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $X$. Suppose that $A$ is contractible. I know that taking the quotient does not affect the homotopy type, that is $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$.

Do we have  also a general result when taking the complement, I mean do we have that $X-A$ is homotopy equivalent to $X-*$ where $*\in A\subset X$ is the base point of $X$ ? If the answer is no then what if the subspace $A$ deformation retracts onto $*$ and not only having the homotopy type of $*$ ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. If $X$ is the circle and $A$ the circle with a point removed, then $A$ and $X/A$ are contractible, but the circle isn't. You need the inclusion from $A$ to $X$ to be a cofibration.

Comment: Yes I see thank you archipelago !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R} = \varnothing$, which does not have the same homotopy type as $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \sim S^0$ even though $\mathbb{R}$ deformation retracts onto a point. For more complicated examples (because this one could look "pathological"), you can remove a half-line from $\mathbb{R}$ and get a contractible space (not homotopy equivalent to $S^0$). Or you can remove a point from $\mathbb{R}^2$, or a line, or the union of two lines, etc., and you'll get differing homotopy types every time.

Comment: So you are saying there is no known result giving standard conditions on $X$ and $A$ under which removing $A$ from $X$ is the same as removing a point from $X$.

Comment: I don't believe so @palio, the result of that operation can be very wild.